# capture journald properties with rsyslog

Tags: linux, systemd, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I am struggling on how to capture `systemd-journald` properties into `rsyslog` files.

#### My setup

- ubuntu inside docker on arm (raspberrypi): `FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04`
- docker command (all subsequent actions taken inside running docker container)

  ```
   $ docker run --privileged -ti --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --cgroup-parent=docker.slice --cgroupns private --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock systemd:origin
  ```
- `rsyslog` under `$ sytemctl status rsyslog`

  ```
   ● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; vendor prese>
        Active: active (running)
   ...
   [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2001.0" x-pid="39758" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
   ...
  ```

#### My plan

Having a small c program to put some information into journal:

```
    #include <systemd/sd-journal.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main(int arcg, char** args) {
      char buffer [50];

      sprintf (buffer, "%lu", (unsigned long)getpid());

      printf("writing to journal\n");

      sd_journal_print(LOG_WARNING, "%s", "a little journal test message");
      sd_journal_send("MESSAGE=%s", "there shoud be a text", "SYSLOG_PID=%s", buffer, "PRIORITY=%i", LOG_ERR, "DOCUMENTATION=%s", "any doc link", "MESSAGE_ID=%s", "e5e4132e441541f89bca0cc3e7be3381", "MEAS_VAL=%d", 1394, NULL);

      return 0;
    }
```

Compile it: `$ gcc joutest.c -lsystemd -o jt`

Execute it: `$ ./jt`

This results inside the journal as `$ journalctl -r -o json-pretty`:

```
    {
      "_GID" : "0",
      "MESSAGE" : "there shoud be a text",
      "_HOSTNAME" : "f1aad951c039",
      "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "jt",
      "_TRANSPORT" : "journal",
      "CODE_FILE" : "joutest.c",
      "DOCUMENTATION" : "any doc link",
      "_BOOT_ID" : "06a36b314cee462591c65a2703c8b2ad",
      "CODE_LINE" : "14",
      "MESSAGE_ID" : "e5e4132e441541f89bca0cc3e7be3381",
      "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "3fffffffff",
      "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1669373862349599",
      "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "init.scope",
      "CODE_FUNC" : "main",
      "_MACHINE_ID" : "5aba31746bf244bba6081297fe061445",
      "SYSLOG_PID" : "39740",
      "PRIORITY" : "3",
      "_COMM" : "jt",
      "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "-.slice",
      "MEAS_VAL" : "1394",
      "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "390853282189",
      "_PID" : "39740",
      "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1669373862336503",
      "_UID" : "0",
      "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/init.scope",
      "__CURSOR" : "s=63a46a30bbbb4b8c9288a9b12c622b37;i=6cb;b=06a36b314cee46>
    }
```

Now as a test, extracting all properties from that journal entry via `rsyslog`; property in the jargon of `rsyslog` in principle is the name of a key in the formatted json entry. But if a property (or key name) matches, the whole dictionary item (key and value) shall be captured

To start with this, I've configured `rsyslog` as:

```
    module(load="imjournal")
    module(load="mmjsonparse")

    action(type="mmjsonparse")

    if $programname == 'jt' and $syslogseverity == 3 then
      action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/jt_err.log" template="RSYSLOG_DebugFormat")
```

This config is located in `/etc/rsyslog.d/filter.conf` and gets automatically included by `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
    # /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file for rsyslog
    #
    # For more information install rsyslog-doc and see
    # /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/configuration/index.html
    #
    # Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
    
    
    #################
    #### MODULES ####
    #################
    
    #module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
    #module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability
    
    # provides UDP syslog reception
    #module(load="imudp")
    #input(type="imudp" port="514")
    
    # provides TCP syslog reception
    #module(load="imtcp")
    #input(type="imtcp" port="514")
    
    # provides kernel logging support and enable non-kernel klog messages
    module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")
    
    ###########################
    #### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
    ###########################
    
    #
    # Use traditional timestamp format.
    # To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
    #
    $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
    
    # Filter duplicated messages
    $RepeatedMsgReduction on
    
    #
    # Set the default permissions for all log files.
    #
    $FileOwner syslog
    $FileGroup adm
    $FileCreateMode 0640
    $DirCreateMode 0755
    $Umask 0022
    $PrivDropToUser syslog
    $PrivDropToGroup syslog
    
    #
    # Where to place spool and state files
    #
    $WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
    
    #
    # Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
    #
    $IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Applied this config: `$ systemctl restart rsyslog`

Which results in the following: `$ cat /var/log/jt_err.log`

```
    Debug line with all properties:
    FROMHOST: 'f1aad951c039', fromhost-ip: '127.0.0.1', HOSTNAME: 
    'f1aad951c039', PRI: 11,
    syslogtag 'jt[39765]:', programname: 'jt', APP-NAME: 'jt', PROCID: 
    '39765', MSGID: '-',
    TIMESTAMP: 'Nov 25 11:47:50', STRUCTURED-DATA: '-',
    msg: ' there shoud be a text'
    escaped msg: ' there shoud be a text'
    inputname: imuxsock rawmsg: '<11>Nov 25 11:47:50 jt[39765]: there 
    shoud be a text'
    $!:{ "msg": "there shoud be a text" }
    $.:
    $/:
```

#### My problem

Looking on the resulting rsyslog, I miss a majority, if not all, of items originating from the journal entry.
There is really no property (key) matching. Shouldn't be there all properties matched as it is a debug output?

Specifically I am concentrating on my custom property, `MEAS_VAL`, it is not there.
The only property which occurs is "msg", which by the way is questionable whether it is a match of the journal, since the originating property name attached to the resulting content `"there shoud be a text"` is `MESSAGE`

So it feels that I don't hit the whole journal capturing mechanism at all, why?

#### Can we be sure that `imjournal` gets loaded properly?

I would say yes because of `systemd's` startup messages:

```
    Nov 28 16:27:38 f1aad951c039 rsyslogd[144703]: imjournal: Journal indicates no msgs when positioned at head.  [v8.2212.0.master try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
    Nov 28 16:27:38 f1aad951c039 rsyslogd[144703]: imjournal: journal files changed, reloading...  [v8.2212.0.master try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
    Nov 28 16:27:38 f1aad951c039 rsyslogd[144703]: imjournal: Journal indicates no msgs when positioned at head.  [v8.2212.0.master try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

#### Edit 2022-11-29

Meanwhile I've compiled my own version 8.2212.0.master. But the phenomenon persists.

Comment: Are you sure imjournal is being loaded? It looks like you're still receiving messages via journald's forwarding to the traditional syslog socket (imuxsock) which is never going to see any metadata. Are you trying to capture messages being sent from outside the container?

Comment: yes, I can be absolutely sure, because the systemd's startup message prove that, see my edit. Everything works inside the container. No traffic is going out- or into the container.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly... Is it, that rsyslog is not *receiving* most of the logs (what does *most* mean)? Or is the problem that it doesn't properly parse it? Also, is `/var/logjt_err.log` the output of rsyslogd?

Comment: @eDonkey: the problem is, rsyslog doesn't do what it is supposed to should do: parsing structured data and output it as a (debug) result. The [doc](https://rsyslog-doc-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/mmjsonparse.html) tells it should parse journal data as json. So there must be json structured journal data, which answers your second question. And I did not talk about _most of the logs_, so _what does most mean_ can only be answered by yourself

Comment: Linking a related question [How to setup syslog forwarding for systemd journal namespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729863/21203). Maybe this simple Answer is what you need, requires adjustments to both the journal `LogNamespace` and `rsyslog.conf`.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing most items originating from the journal, because both templates `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat` and `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` do not have the needed properties (See [Reserved template names](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html#reserved-template-names)). `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat`, however, includes atleast some fields, e.g. `procid`, `msgid` and `structured-data` - which can be seen in the output you've provided.

This means, that if you want to include all the fields, you'll have to create your own template.

The journal fields are stored in key-value pairs. The `imjournal` module is able to parse these key-value pairs and generate the `jsonf` property,
which then can be used to access fields of the log message as if they were fields in a JSON object.

```
# load imjournal module
module(load="imjournal")

# specify journal as input source
input(type="imjournal")

template(name="journalTemplate" type="list") {
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="syslogtag")
    constant(value=": {")
    property(name="jsonf")
    constant(value="}")
}

if $programname == 'jt' and $syslogseverity == 3 then {
  action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/jt_err.log" template="journalTemplate")
  stop
}
```

The output of the provided log would then look something like the following:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss myHostname syslogtag: {"_GID" : "0", "MESSAGE" : "there shoud be a text", ... }
```

---

As seen in the log above, the output of the provided properties will be in JSON. By using the `json` property parser this can be prevented, as the output can be tailored as desired. If this is used, however, each property must be defined specifically.

```
template(name="journalTemplate" type="list") {
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="syslogtag")
    constant(value=": _GID=")
    property(name="$._GID" format="json")
    constant(value=" MESSAGE=")
    property(name="$.MESSAGE" format="json")
    constant(value=" _HOSTNAME=")
    property(name="$._HOSTNAME" format="json")
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you got a valuable explanation, why it shouldn't work with the approach in the question? Have you been trying out (proofed) your suggestion?

Comment: AFAIK, if you want to include all the fields, you can't use any standard templates. And yes, I've used the log you provided to test this. I've edited the answer to include this.

Comment: I do not agree with you. The debug template has a `property(name="structured-data")` and thus should be able to read all journal properties. Whether the output is json formatted or simple text is another question and not part of the whole problem. Why would the maintainers of rsyslog, especially David Lang, ask so often for a debug output with `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat`? `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` is out of scope here.

Comment: I see your point, but to my knowledge, this only applies to syslog messages, as it needs to be defined what fields the `property(name="structured-data")` should include. And regarding `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat`, you're using it in your config, that's why I included it.

Comment: Can you give a link to a docu, where it is explained that `structured-data` needs to be especially fine-grained declared. How did you come to your knowledge?

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant to say. The `structured-data` is used in the [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.3) standard and can contain various properties, so it is up to the logging system to decide which specific fields it wants to use. Journal does not use RFC5424 and AFAIK does not follow any specific standard.